# I need sprite to keep moving after shooting a bullet

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I've made a very very basic game in pygame, where the only actions possible are moving left, moving right and shooting a bullet upwards. My problem is that when I shoot, my player sprite stays still while the bullet travels upward. How can I remedy this? I'm very new to pygame, so I'd appreciate any and all help.

```
#importing needed libraries
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *


#Class for the Player
class Player():
    def __init__(self,surf,xpos,ypos):
        self.image=pygame.image.load("cat1.png").convert_alpha()
        self.x=xpos
        self.y=ypos
        self.surface=surf
    def keys(self):
        dist=10
        key=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            if self.x<500:
                self.x+=dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            if self.x!=0:
                self.x-=dist
    def draw(self,surface):
        self.surface.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))

#Class for the bullet which inherits the Player Class
class Weapon(Player):
    def __init__(self,surf,xpos,ypos,bg,wxpos,wypos):
        Player.__init__(self,surf,xpos,ypos)
        self.wimage=pygame.image.load("bullet.png").convert_alpha()
        self.wx=wxpos
        self.wy=wypos
        self.background=bg

    def Shoot(self):
        dist=10
        while self.wy>0:
            self.surface.blit(self.background,(0,0))
            self.surface.blit(self.image,(self.x,self.y))
            self.surface.blit(self.wimage,(self.wx,self.wy))
            self.wy-=dist
            pygame.display.update()

#initialising pygame
pygame.init()

FPS=30
fpsClock=pygame.time.Clock()

#creating display window
DISPLAYSURF=pygame.display.set_mode((577,472),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Animation')


WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
background=pygame.image.load("background.png")
DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)

#creating player
player=Player(DISPLAYSURF,50,360)

#main game loop
while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            weapon=Weapon(DISPLAYSURF,player.x,player.y,background,player.x+25,player.y)
            player.draw(DISPLAYSURF)
            weapon.Shoot()

    player.keys()
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(background,(0,0))
    player.draw(DISPLAYSURF)

    pygame.display.update()
    fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Not detailing the way to do this here, but you need to use a thread or a subroutine. Basically, what you want is having many objects running at the same time, so you need to parallelize their actions.

Comment: you can't use `while` loop in `Shoot`. You have to move it inside `while True` (mainloop).

Comment: `Shoot` has to be class - similar to Player - with `draw()` to display and `update()` to move it only few pixel in every loop of mainloop. Mainloop wil do all job.

Answer (score 0):

`Shoot` has to be class like Player with `draw()` and `update()` which moves bullet only `self.dist` pixels. If you call it in mainloop then you get moving bullet and you can move player.

It is simple example. Read more about [pygame.sprite.Sprite()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html), [pygame.sprite.Group()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) and [pygame.Rect()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html)

And see [Program Arcade Games With Python And Pygame](http://programarcadegames.com/)

```
import pygame
import sys

# --- constants ----

FPS = 30

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

# --- classes ---

class Player():

    def __init__(self, surface, x, y):
        self.surface = surface
        self.image = pygame.image.load("cat1.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.dist = 10

    def keys(self):
        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if key[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            if self.rect.x < 500:
                self.rect.x += self.dist
        elif key[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            if self.rect.x >= 0:
                self.rect.x -= self.dist

    def draw(self):
        self.surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)


class Bullet():

    def __init__(self, surface, x, y):
        self.surface = surface
        self.image = pygame.image.load("bullet.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.dist = 10
        self.dead = False

    def draw(self):
        self.surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        if self.rect.y > 0:
            self.rect.y -= self.dist
        else:
            self.dead = True

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((577,472),0,32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Animation')

background = pygame.image.load("background.png")
player = Player(display, 50, 360)

fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()

bullets = []

while True:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            b = Bullet(display, player.rect.x, player.rect.y)
            bullets.append(b)

    # --- updates ---

    player.keys()

    # moves bullets
    for b in bullets:
        b.update()

    # remove "dead" bullets
    bullets = [b for b in bullets if not b.dead]

    # --- draws ---

    display.blit(background, (0,0))

    player.draw()

    for b in bullets:
        b.draw()

    pygame.display.update()

    # --- FPS ---
    fps_clock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely look into those resources!